# What does it mean to have a small p value and an OR=1?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, p-value, odds-ratio

As the questions says, in a logistic regression I have small p value for a variable indicating statistical significance (p = 0.001), however the odds ratio at a 95% confidence interval is 0.999 (both upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval are also 0.999). How to interpret that? I can reject my null hypothesis, but the variable has the same effect on both classes? How can I have a small p value if that is the case?

Here is some sample output:

```
                      OR        2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)           1.4315133 0.9037277 2.2814700
variable 1            0.9999999 0.9999998 0.9999999
variable 2            1.3925532 1.2386589 1.5640352

                   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        0.128767    
variable 1         0.00108 **
variable 2         0.00000002594048139 ***
```

It is unclear to me how to interpret the results for variable 1.

Comment: I am re-reading your question. You are past the idea that $\text{OR}=e^{\beta}$, am I right?

Comment: I added the results in case it helps.

Comment: That helps understanding your question...

Comment: what is the range of variable 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P-values are not perfectly connected to the magnitude of an effect. For one, if you have an extremely large sample size, it is perfectly possible to have an extremely tiny effect size paired with what most would consider a small p-value.

For example, a simple correlation of 0.01 when paired with a sample size of 100K will have a one-tailed p-value of 0.00078259.

http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=44 (try it out yourself)

P-values are not an indication of effect size in and of themselves and say nothing about the magnitude of the relationship.

At some point, the binary decision process of traditional significance testing loses its utility, and you might be at that point with your data.

In terms of interpretation, the most straightforward interpretation is that you have a very, very small effect made significant on the back of an extremely large sample size.

Comment: OK, thanks, @Reg. It seems that this is the only explanation. I posted the results in the edit of my question. My sample has about 10,000 observations. So, it is not that large I would say.

Comment: 10K is very large in some worlds, modest in others. I would also be curious as to what the relationship between variable 1 and variable 2 is like, and what the relationship of variable 1 (in isolation) to the outcome is like. I didn't realize it was a multivariate case when I answered, but collinearity can also do some very strange things to individual predictors when placed in a multivariate situation.

Comment: It still stays significant on its own with similar p value and the same odds ratio and confidence intervals as above. However, I think the effect might be indeed very small. Especially, variable 1 can range from 0 to 1,000,000, but most of the values are probably confined to a much smaller range, say, 1,000 to 2,000 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Odds ratio (OR) is equal to the estimated increase in the log-odds of the outcome *per unit increase* in the input variable. Hence, the value of OR is affected by the *scale* of the input variable. Based on your comment above, it does look like Variable_1 has a wide range (large scale).

Since the OR for Variable_1 is less than one, you can deduct the value from 1 to get 0.11, multiply that by 100, and interpret it as follows: For every 100 unit increase in Variable_1, the log odds of the outcome decreases by 11%.

As per the apparent contradiction between p-value and OR, I agree with what @reg has mentioned in his answer above; the p-value doesn't tell you the *magnitude* of the effect.